# Make dropdown list always open (PrimeNg)

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, primeng

[image]

Is there a way to always display the dropdown list/always have the dropdown list open? Currently the dropdown only appears when the input box is clicked. I know it sounds kind of silly but just wondering if there is a way to get it done or maybe a word around?

I am now using PrimeNg AutoComplete Multiple mode for the dropdown but I think the general mechanism for the dropdown is pretty much the same so maybe there is a common way to solve this?

Comment: I need something similar like opening dropdown after input box focus. Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: You can have look at somewhat similar Listbox component
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/listbox

Comment: I would recommend looking at another option that is using p-listbox with filter enable, I think that makes your job by default.

Answer (score 1):

I can say, that p-dropdown doesn't have this possibility out of the box. You can do a hack: assign a class to your dropdown:

```
    <p-dropdown [styleClass]="'your-class'" ...
```

And you can open the dropdown when you need it (but after template is initialized) using code like:

```
    const yourDropdown = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".unique-class");

    if (yourDropdown) {
        yourDropdown.click();
    }
```

P.S.
This is just an example. It's better to improve it. For example, use id instead of class.